# Finding theta so that a boat travels due east

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces

A boat starts travelling out at 30 degrees North of East on a lake at 20km/hr relative to the water. There is a current in the lake that is 5km/hr at a direction of 40 degrees South of East. *Note: The velocity of the water is measured from the shore.

I'm having a bit of trouble finding the required $\theta$ so that the boat travels due east. I found $v_b$, the velocity of the boat, by adding the velocity of the boat relative to the water, and the velocity of the water.

By doing so I got,

$v_b$ = $(20cos(\theta)+3.83)i + (20sin(\theta)-3.2)j$

From here I'm stuck. I thought by letting the $j$ component of $v_b$ equal the $j$ component of the water vector and rearranging for theta, I'd get the answer, but I of course get 0.

Comment: Do you mean $\theta$ rather than 30? otherwise, the velocity of the boat is predetermined and it cannot travel due East.

Comment: 30 degrees was for the earlier questions, now it's asking for $\theta$ required to travel due East.

Comment: so the j component is zero, which gives you $\theta$

Comment: So it would be $20sin(\theta) - 3.21$ = $0$? Hence, $\theta$ = $9.24$ degrees?

Comment: yes that's right...